# Sort NSArray of NSStrings by a containing Number in the String. Rearrange String so Number is in the beginning?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting

I have an array of string, that look like this

```
"/var/folders/zy/zy4FzDGQEUuq9jZ1hTRFHk+++TI/-Tmp-/tarDir0172809001305545247/0516_GTB_HP_01.pdf"
"/var/folders/zy/zy4FzDGQEUuq9jZ1hTRFHk+++TI/-Tmp-/tarDir0172809001305545247/0516_ETB_HP_28.pdf"
```

As you can see, tehy differ by the number and the character `G` or `E`.
 When I sort them like this, they are sorted by `GTB` / `ETB` and then by the number at the end. But what I want is first to have them sorted by number and then by the letter E or G.
What I should mention is, that there can occur Strings that have the same number in the end and just differ by  `G` or `E`.

So what I thought of, was maybe simply exchanging the number in the end with the characters `ETB` or `GTB`.
What's the most elegant way to do this? 
Or do u have any other suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom comparator for your sort in NSArray or NSMutableArray. Inside that function you could split the string in multiple parts and compare them the way you want (first the numbers, and if those are equal the GTB / ETB)

Comment: I have never used custom comparators. Could you give me a hint or a link?

Comment: I haven't got a lot of time to write out your case, but check this question, it does exactly the same but with another sort criterium:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001744/sorting-nsarray-of-nsstrings-by-match-occurrence

Answer (score 1):

If you can target iOS 4.x and above you can use blocks

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    // obj1 and obj2 are 2 strings from you array
    // here you write your own logic to understand if obj1 <=> obj2
    // here's an example in pseudo code
    if (obj1 > obj2)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    if (obj1 < obj2)
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```